# replace a text with another within a tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm sure it's stupidly easy, but how can I replace just the text within an html tag. For instance, from this:

```
<div style="display: block;">blah blah</div>
<a href="#" style="display: inline; ">(Old text)</a>
```

to this:

```
<div style="display: block;">blah blah</div>
<a href="#" style="display: inline; ">(New text)</a>
```

replace Old text => New text
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just select the element and change its contents

```
$("a").html("(New Text)");
```

**References**

- [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [text](http://api.jquery.com/text/)
- [jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

Answer (score 3):

Put an id on the element containing the text:

```
<div style="display: block;">blah blah</div><a href="#" style="display: inline; " id="replaceme">(Old text)</a>
```

And use

```
$('#replaceme').html('New text');
```

This is the basic, I think you can work it out from here :)

Answer (score 0):

First, give your element an ID so you can refer to it:

```
<a id="something" href="#" style="display: inline; ">(Old text)</a>
```

Then use the string [`replace`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) function:

```
var str = $('#something').text();
$('#something').text(str.replace('Old text', 'New text'));
```